# How to connect Visual Studio with Dynamics CRM and do coding to customize the CRM?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, microsoft-dynamics

I am having Dynamics CRM online and Visual Studio Community 2017 installed on my machine.How can I customize Dynamics CRM using the code in Visual Studio and synchronize them?

I have to integrate my instance with Twilio using Visual Studio.But I have no idea about how to synchronize Visual Studio to make changed in the Dynamics CRM.
Can anyone please help me out on this?

Comment: There is not out-of-box solution that comes with Visual Studio. Check [MS CRM ALM](https://www.google.com/search?q=ms+crm+alm) (ALM = Application Lifecycle Management) to explore various 3rd party tools and MS best practices. Basically it boils down to download a CRM Solution, unpack the elements into your VS project and backward.

Comment: If you want to roll your own, the CRM SDK comes with a tool called *SolutionPackager.exe* (located in `SDK\Bin`) that handles unpacking and packing CRM Solution .zip files into a (more or less) suitable folder structure.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use the SolutionPackager.exe tool to code my own logic and add it to my instance of CRM?

Comment: See [Use the SolutionPackager tool to compress and extract a solution file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602987.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend installing something like [CRM Developer Extensions](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMDeveloperExtensions) as an addon to your Visual Studio. This will provide you with templates for your extensions and allow you to publish Web Resources and assemblies directly to CRM from Visual Studio.

However for development purposes, it isn't necessary to keep files such as Web Resources synchronised the whole time. I'd recommend only synchronising them once they've been tested and are ready to be deployed, even just to a sandbox CRM Organisation.

Instead, when developing Web Resources, you can debug them using Fiddler. Read [this blog post](http://develop1.net/public/post/Fiddler2-The-tool-that-gives-you-Superpowers-Part-2.aspx) on how to set up Fiddler's AutoResponder for CRM.